# Adding incoming categories in json with laravel attach() method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

Json file...

```
{'code': '200',
 'msg': '',
 'result': [{'_cdate': '',
              '_date': '2022-05-07 17:45:26.00',
              '_key': '9146247893236409738',
              '_key_cts_brand': 'brand',
              '_key_cts_title': 'product title',
              '_key_cts_price': '100',
    'm_categories': [
        {'_cdate': '2021-11-29 10:40:02.00',
          '_date': '2022-05-07 17:45:26.00',
          '_key': '9079201',
          'key_cts_item_category_1': '8972814',
          'key_cts_item_category_2': '9079130',
          'key_cts_item_category_3': '9079171',
          'key_cts_item_category_4': '8976016',
          'key_cts_item_category_5': '0',
          'key_cts_item_category_6': '0',
          'key_cts_stock': '9146247893236409738',
          '_key_top_1': '',
          '_key_top_2': '8972814',
          '_key_top_3': '9079130',
          '_key_top_4': '',
          '_key_top_5': '',
          '_key_top_6': '',
        }
    ]
```

I have 6 categories coming from json.
Categories come with key_cts_item_category tag. I'm trying to print them to my database them with attach() on the Laravel side.

```
$product = new Product();
$product->brand_id =  $result['_key_cts_brand'];
$product->title =  $result['_key_cts_title'];
$product->price =  $result['_key_cts_price'];
$product->save();

foreach($result['m_categories'] as $cats){
    Category::find($cats['key_cts_item_category_1']);
    $product->categories()->detach();
    $product->categories()->attach(array($cats['key_cts_item_category_1'],$cats['key_cts_item_category_2'],$cats['key_cts_item_category_3'],$cats['key_cts_item_category_4'],$cats['key_cts_item_category_5'],$cats['key_cts_item_category_6']));
}
```

I did something like above, but it doesn't work properly.
How can I check the incoming categories and add them all?

database ::
There are indexes and foreign_key in the database.

```
product_categories
product_id  -  category_id
9079201         8972814
9079201         9079130
9079201         9079171
9079201         8976016
```

I'm trying to get an image like this

Comment: i think you don't need to use loop and simply attach values of array. use  $product->categories()->attach(array($result['key_cts_item_category_1'],$result['key_cts_item_category_2'],$result['key_cts_item_category_3'],$result['key_cts_item_category_4'],$result['key_cts_item_category_5'],$result['key_cts_item_category_6'])); and check

Comment: unfortunately I can't get it without looping. There are different entries above and below.